# I need a circuit that would stay on after being triggered

Tags: sensor, signal, circuit-design, flipflop, robotics

I am a year one electrical engineering student, and I am currently doing a project about building an electrical robot car. One of the required features of the car is to add a front sensor to the front, and it will continuously reverse backwards when it detects a white wall. (So, in other words, it will continual to move backwards even after it can't detect the wall anymore) But, I am having problems on how to implement this.

The front sensor provided will be on high when it detects nothing in front, and on low when it detects a white wall. I know that I need the signal to stay on low after it detects the wall. So I need a circuit that would stay in the new state after being triggered.

I hope I have my question clear enough... thank you.

P.S. Some of the ideas discussed in class were D flip flops, I'm not sure if that's the idea to be put in here.

P.S. I need to mention that we are only allow to use ICs like D flip flop, JK flip flop, counter. comparators, timers, not gates, or gates, and gates, and other basic gates ICs.

Comment: You need a bistable (two-state) circuit. You can certainly do this with a D flip-flop, with a clock signal triggered on the falling edge of the sensor output signal.

Comment: hmmm... sorry I don't think I get it. I've been researching a lot on D flip flops but I never quite get the concept. Is it possible to make more clear?? Thanks.

Comment: How long do you want it to stay in the new state after being triggered? Forever? Right now it sounds like the first time it hits a wall it will reverse forever.

Comment: A D flip-flop changes its output state (HIGH/LOW) on the rising edge of the clock depending on the state of the D input. If the clock goes HIGH and the D input is HIGH, then the Q output also goes HIGH. If the clock goes HIGH and the D input is LOW, then the Q output goes low. The output keeps its state between rising edges of the clock

Comment: @mkeith That is unless there is another sensor on the other side that triggers the flip-flop in reverse to make it switch direction again

Comment: @mekeith yeah I do want it to stay on forever, cause the instruction says it just needs to reverse at least 30cm and the demonstration ends.

Comment: @DerStrom8 but how could I make the original out put be high in the first place, then low when triggered. does that mean I have to manually make it to high at first, and then move D to low so when it senses the wall it goes to low?

Comment: @Cherub The D flops may include both a SET and RESET. If so, make sure to use the SET line with whatever you use to initialize the whole system. That will ensure that it starts as high. Tie the /Q to the D input. When the necessary clock arrives (properly arranged), the D flop will copy the /Q (low at the time) to the new Q output.

Comment: @jonk ohh! I think it does. I'm using a hd74ls74ap D flip flop IC and I just looked that it has preset and clear with it. thanks!

Comment: @Cherub So I added an explicit diagram. Hopefully, that is what you are now thinking.

Comment: you could have two sensors OR'd low or input to NAND for output normally low then if either front or rear sees a wall it reverses direction with a Toggle and shown by @jonk  The sensor comparator ought to be a Schmitt Trigger.  Then the demo runs until you turn it off or it hits a dark wall. with an IR emitter, it can work in the dark off dark walls too.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah. But since the OP didn't ask about the sensor, I didn't add that. But there's no question that hysteresis would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. To summarize, then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7u9lz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hopefully, that matches up with what you are now thinking. This assumes that setting CLEAR to ground avoids clearing the FF. You'll need to activate the PRESET line whenever you reset things and start everything up before starting.

---

It's important to note that the simplicity of the above circuit depends on the fact that your sensor signal is clean and doesn't repeat itself. The Photon makes a good point. So here's another approach that covers his comment:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fazZuH.png)</sup>

Which you use depends, I suppose. But given your stated interest, I think The Photon's point is more important and that you should use the second circuit and not the first. Just to be safe.

Comment: @ThePhoton Indeed. But I don't know the sensor situation. Point is worth adding to my answer, though. Added. And thanks!

Comment: So I was just experimenting it on the breadboard and I couldn't get it to preset somehow. output Q always comes out to be same as D.

Comment: @Cherub If there is a PRESET and a CLEAR, they should do opposite things to Q and they should ignore D. Keep the clock line tied to VCC or ground, though. If you float it, who knows? That may be your problem, given your observation.

Answer (score 0):

I see suggestions using logic gates and flip-flops.

Has anyone considered a much simpler and cheaper approach like using a SCR?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier

Seems much simpler and yet attends the requirements.  SCRs have the exact purpose of starting to conduct when the gate is stimulated while they keep conducting after the stimulus is interrupted.

The gate should be connected to the sensor, the anode to VCC (better if protected by a current limiting resistor) and the cathode (with a pull-down resistor) will output the logic level matching the requirement.

Reset button: A normally-closed momentary switch can be added between the VCC and the anode resistor to serve as the reset button.

Comment: A SCR isn't really cheaper than a jellybean DFF IC in this day and age...

Comment: Unfortunately, the professor doesn't let us use ICs that are not provide tho.

Answer (score -1):

.............

This should work:

[image]